# PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) - undefined is not a constructor (evaluating ‘re.exec(obj)’) - Chai Test Case For React

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, karma-mocha, mocha-phantomjs

**Test case React For Component:**

I am trying to write a test case which calls a function in .jsx file passing object as argument from spec.js file to test a function return value of react component.

I have the pasted the code and error message, I am getting.

**What could be cause for the error? any workaround to solve the error?**

**Below is the Test case code:**

```
it(‘should render without problems OverlayAddExtraSimComponent restrictedtemplate type’, () => {
let overlayAddExtraSimObj = {code:‘AddOneExtraSimChange_ProductChangeButtons_TechnicalCategorization’},
overlayAddExtraSimVal;

overlayAddExtraSimVal = addExtraSim._restrictedToBundleTemplate(overlayAddExtraSimObj);
expect(overlayAddExtraSimVal).to.match('AddOneExtraSimChange');
});
```

**Below is the Error Message:**

> FAILED TESTS: OverlayAddExtraSim Component × should render without
>   problems OverlayAddExtraSimComponent restrictedtempl ate type
>   PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) undefined is not a constructor
>   (evaluating ‘re.exec(obj)’)
>   assertMatch@node_modules/chai/chai.js:1364:16
>   node_modules/chai/chai.js:4192:30
>   webpack:///src/components/overlay/overlay-add-extra-sim/overlay-add-extra-sim.spec.js:45:41 <- test/loadtests.js:279945:41

Note: I have tried installing phantomjs-polyfill-object-assign,babel-polyfill.

Kindly let me know, what could be the cause for this error and solution for it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have not the answer but few suggestions, you have to improve all the question a lot. A well-written question has higher chances to get an answer. I think that the part that summarizes the "question", in your post, should be better highlighted (where is the ->?). You have done a lot of formatting errors--e.g: "code" format for normal text. This makes your question unreadable.

Comment: Also try to better separate context/topic description, environment description, actions performed, expected outcome, obtained errors (.. I also give far far faar more informations), and the question. You have to spend more time creating the question or people is not going to spend their time answering.

Comment: Hope now you understand